# How do I set up an alias for the terminal command 'chromium-browser'?

Tags: html, linux, browser, terminal, alias

At the moment, to test my webpage, I run the terminal command: `chromium-browser index.html`
What are some more efficient alternatives?

Chromium Projects shows the following:

[image: Chromium Projects resource]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suggest in the title, you can setup an alias:

```
alias cbi='chromium-browser index.html'
```

Then, next time, just type cbi.